# Error in cookie expiration date for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am having problem with the cookie expiry date on Chrome.  I set two cookies like this using ColdFusion:

```
<cfset thekey = generatesecretkey("DESEDE")>
<cfcookie name="cookie1" value="#Hash(userid&thekey,'SHA-256')#" httponly="true" >
<cfcookie name="cookie2" value="#thekey#" httponly="true" >
```

They have been working for a while.  However, after the upgrade to ColdFusion 10 and working with Chrome, weird thing started to happen.  It only happened with Chrome browser. Other browsers do not have this issue:

When these two cookies are set they both end up with an expiry date of **Wednesday December 31, 1969 at 7:00:11 PM**

This puzzled me greatly.  I didn't set any expiry date as you can see. So the default is *session only*.  They are supposed to expire at the end of user's session.  My question is where is this date come from?  Is it from the ColdFusion 10 server or Chrome?  I am lost as to why this date is appearing on the cookie's *Expires* field in Chrome.  With this expiry date, the cookies are considered expired already and won't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the expiry date using the expires attribute?

Comment: @JackPilowsky I have not because I want it to expire for session and also want to find out the root cause.  The default for the expire parameter in cfcookie function supposed to be "session only".  Since it only happen on Chrome I am suspecting it may be Chrome bug.

Comment: Try setting it expressively to session only. See if that works

Comment: The CF crashed when I added expires="session only".

Comment: You were already using session only, by omitting "expires". "Session Only" is not an allowed value, only: dates, number of days, "now" or "never".

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Session cookie is set by not having an expires field but Chrome always shows the expires as 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z. Any updates?

Answer (score 15):

For session cookies Chrome Dev Tools just show that strange expiration date which actually doesn't play any role.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses this date by default, unless you explicitly specify the cookie's lifetime.

Similar question:
[What does a cookie with 1969 as the expiration date mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497459/what-does-a-cookie-with-1969-as-the-expiration-date-mean)