# Why does cookie persist in Chrome dev tools after expiry

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

Under certain circumstances (which are that the server-stored session has expired and been deleted while the browser was inactive for a long period of time) I get a cookie that gets stuck in the browser. It has expired but which mysteriously persists regardless. I don't seem to be able to get it to clear, even when I set the expiry date to the past.

I can see the Expires / Max age:

```
1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z
```

But even after a page refresh that cookie is still showing with the same URL and path and same Name and Value.

This is causing my application state to break as in this particular condition it expects the cookie to clear so that the front-end can properly acknowledge and understand that the session is ended and not recoverable.

This is Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
On Mac OS X 12.10.6

I should add that I haven't tested this on other browsers – because it's difficult to test. It may or may not happen on them.

Comment: Maybe because it's session cookie: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522736/error-in-cookie-expiration-date-for-chrome